# Chromatic polynomial of a cycle on n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to compute the chromatic polynomial of a cycle on n vertices, and I saw the answer [Prove that the chromatic polynomial of a cycle graph $C_{n}$ equals $(k-1)^{n} + (k-1)(-1)^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91009/prove-that-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-cycle-graph-c-n-equals-k-1n)

The answer makes sense to me. I used another method which gave me a different answer, but I don't know why it is wrong. The following is my proof: 
Pick one vertex to start with, there are x possible colors we can assign to that vertex. Assign colors clockwise, the next (n-2) vertex should each be assigned a different color than the previous vertex, so there are (x-1) possile colors we can assign to each of them. For the last remaining vertex, it should be assigned a different color with both its previous vertex and the first vertex, so there are (x-2) possible colors we can assign. 
Therefore, the chromatic polynomial is $$x(x-1)^{n-2}(x-2)$$.

Why is this wrong?

Comment: What if the previous vertex of the last vertex and the first vertex have the same colour? Then there will be $x-1$ possibilities for the last vertex.

Comment: I see! Thank you!