# Find the Chromatic Polynomial of the graph given below

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[I want to find the chromatic polynomial for this graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXMqy.png)

My polynomial was x(x-1)((x-2)^2) but i am not sure that this is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did you get that polynomial?

Comment: P(K3,x).P(K3,x)/P(K2,x)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach and answer is correct, the graph is a 2-clique sum of two $K_3$'s and thus the chromatic polynomial $\frac{P(K_3,x)P(K_3,x)}{x(x-1)}$.

I offer an alternative solution.
We apply the [deletion-contraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula) in this scenario.

We let your graph be $G$. Removing the diagonal $xv$, we obtain $P(G,x)=P(G-xv,x)- P(G/xv,x)=P(C_4,x)-P(P_3,x)$.

The characteristic polynomial for [cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91009/prove-that-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-cycle-graph-c-n-equals-k-1n) and [paths](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/fouts.pdf) are well known.

Thus, $P(G,x)= (x-1)^4+(-1)^4(x-1)-x(x-1)^2=x(x-1)(x-2)^2$.